# Ignoring "es6!" file prefix in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

We have a bunch of legacy code that's importing ES6 modules using

`import x from 'es6!xpath'`

We can't actually change those at the moment so I need webpack to basically ignore the `es6!` prefix at build time and act as if I'd just done

`import x from 'xpath'`

Is there anyway of doing that?

Comment: The api just allow us to avoid the extension, hard to say how to do what you want. But let me ask you why you can't change the names of those files.

Comment: Because it's a shared component with code that still uses RequireJS and an ES6 loader (that requires the prefix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack but add this to your `webpack.config` where the alias overwrites the `es6!`

```
const config = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'es6!': ''
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I ended up going for. Although the exclamation mark isn't needed